# Is there the way using PhyML with Smart Model Selection in Biopython?

Tags: python, biopython

Now, I'm searching the way using PhyML with Smart Model Selection in Biopython.

According to the official literature of PhyML (SMS: Smart Model Selection in PhyML:https://academic.oup.com/mbe/article/34/9/2422/3788860), there is the command-line interface of model selection (but I can't find anywhere). Biopython has a module called `from Bio.Phylo.Applications import PhymlCommandline` and make it possible to execute the PyhML from python script.

Is there the way to integrate the PhymlCommandline and Smart Model Selection in Python ?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the source code of SMS from the [Docs and Materials section](http://www.atgc-montpellier.fr/sms/binaries.php) of the website of the ATGC Montpelier bioinformatics platform.

The code is a combination of several shell scripts and uses R and PhyML under the hood.

So download the zip file, unpack it and  make sure you have R installed.

```
$ unzip sms-1.8.1.zip
[...]
$ cd sms-1.8.1
sms-1.8.1 $ R --version
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"
```

the code relies on PhyML to compute likelihood scores. PhyML sources are embedded within the SMS tarball. Required package to compile:

- for Debian  : 'build-essential'

  `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
- for SuSE    : 'devel_basis'

  `sudo zypper install --type pattern devel_basis`
- for Red Hat : 'C Development Tools and Libraries'

  `sudo yum -y -v groupinstall "C Development Tools and Libraries"`

Please  note that  spaces in  directory names  can cause  problems. Now we need to build the PhyML source.

```
sms-1.8.1 $ make all
[...]
```

Then make the shell script executable.

```
sms-1.8.1 $ chmod +x ./sms.sh
```

You can now run SMS using the following command structure

```
 ./sms.sh -i [input-msa] -d [data-type]
```

where:

- `[input-msa]` is your input data alignment in PHYLIP format
- `[data-type]` can be `aa` for amino-acids data or `nt` for DNA

Optional parameters are:

```
 -o : Path to the SMS output directory
 -c : Criterion to use 'aic' or 'bic'
 -u : Input tree in Newick format
 -t : Add this option to infer a PhyML tree with selected model
 -s : Type of tree improvement 'NNI' or 'SPR'
 -r : Number of random starting trees
 -b - Branch support (aLRT or bootstrap replicates)
 -h : Prints help
```

For example,  using the [primatesNT.phy](http://www.atgc-montpellier.fr/phyml-sms/primatesNT.phy) example file from [The Phylogenetic Handbook](https://www.kuleuven.be/aidslab/phylogenybook/home.html):

```
sms-1.8.1 $ ./sms.sh -i primatesNT.phy -d nt -c bic
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                     Starting SMS v1.8.1
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Input alignment    : primatesNT.phy
Data type          : DNA
Number of taxa     : 21
Number of sites    : 1500
Number of branches : 39
Criterion          : BIC
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Step 1 : Set a fixed topology
        BIC=13172.69687
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Step 2 : Select the best decoration
        BIC=13165.48751 decoration : '+G'
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Step 3 : Select the best matrix
        BIC=13155.36733 matrix : 'HKY85'
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Step 4 : Select the best final decoration
        BIC=13155.36733 decoration : '+G'
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Selected model                          : HKY85 +G
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Substitution model                      : HKY85
Equilibrium frequencies                 : ML optimized
Transition / transversion ratio         : estimated
Proportion of invariable sites          : fixed (0.0)
Number of substitution rate categories  : 4
Gamma shape parameter                   : estimated (0.587)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Suggested citations:
SMS
 Vincent Lefort, Jean-Emmanuel Longueville, Olivier Gascuel.
 "SMS: Smart Model Selection in PhyML."
 Molecular Biology and Evolution, msx149, 2017.
PhyML
 S. Guindon, JF. Dufayard, V. Lefort, M. Anisimova, W. Hordijk, O. Gascuel
 "New algorithms and methods to estimate maximum-likelihood phylogenies: assessing the performance of PhyML 3.0."
 Systematic Biology. 2010. 59(3):307-321.
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Thank you for  your reply. I downloaded the scripts and conducted the scripts via cygwin (because my computer is windows10). But I got the error (cp: cannot stat ''.../sms-1.8.1/sms/sms.phy_phyml_tree_GTR+G+I+F-lr.txt'':No such file or directory) during the processing. Did you know the solution ?

Comment: You are maybe executing the command from the wrong directory? Can you manually confirm that there is a file named `sms.phy_phyml_tree_GTR+G+I+F-lr.txt` in the `sms` subdirectory?